# Is there a way to view Qgis models from version 2.14 so they can be recreated in 3.0

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I upgraded my qgis version from 2.14 to 3.0 and didn't realize that the models from the graphic modeler are not compatible.  Is there a way to view or read the models so I can recreate them in 3.0?  I have 24 that I use in various project and I would rather not have to build them from scratch again.

Comment: Can't you just open them in QGIS 2.14 and take a screenshot?

Comment: @csk I uninstalled it in order to install 3.0.  There are also settings within each algorithm that I need to look at.

Comment: you can install qgis3 and qgis2 parallel on one machine and have both applications open at the same time. That is not a very good solutions but may be helps you porting the modells

Comment: @brink - I don't think there is a simple method to achieve what you want (I would also do screenshots). You _could_ open up the QGIS 2.14 models in a text editor and see all the values used but it's not easily readable.

Comment: When I updated from QGIS 2.14 to an early version of 2.18, I found that some of the functions were buggy, either giving incorrect results or crashing the program. Since 3.0 is still an early release, you may have similar issues. It's probably not a good idea to rely on the results of calculations performed in 3.0 until it's been out for a while and the major bugs have been worked out. You may want to reinstall 2.14 (or 2.18) for that reason alone.

Comment: Models from 2.14 should be compatible with 2.18. I wonder if opening them in 2.18 and re-saving them would make them compatible with 3.0. Might be worth trying.

Comment: Oh well, that's what you get for trying to get ahead of the curve.  I installed 2.18 and they work.  I guess I'll wait on 3.0 and take 500 screen shots before switching then spend a week building and testing the models.  A simple 'changes' document on the download page would go a long way in avoiding this kind of thing.  I know it's more fun to develop than write technical manuals but hell, just a heads up would be nice.  Thanks for the help everybody!